# jQuery does not update/redraw view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a wrapper DIV that contain two other DIVs which are defined via CSS to float right respectively float left. These two DIVs I  want to set to the same height depending on the larger one of the both. I have tried this with the following code:

```js
var pHeightA;
var pHeightB;
var output = '';

$('.anklickbareartikel-wrapper').each(function(i) {

  pHeightA = $('.anklickbareartikel', this).height();
  pHeightB = $('.anklickartikelbox', this).height();

  output = i + ': ';

  if (pHeightA > pHeightB) {
    $('.anklickartikelbox', this).height(pHeightA);
    output += 'pHeightA > pHeightB |';
  }

  if (pHeightB > pHeightA) {
    $('.anklickbareartikel', this).height(pHeightB);
    output += 'pHeightB > pHeightA |';
  }

  //alert( output + 'Original: A ' + pHeightA + ' / B ' + pHeightB + ' // Nach Änderung: A ' + $('.anklickbareartikel', this).height() + ' / ' + $('.anklickartikelbox', this).height() );

});
```

```css
.anklickbareartikel-wrapper {
  height: auto;
}

.anklickbareartikel {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  background: #fffdfb;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.anklickartikelbox {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 50px 90px;
}

.anklickartikelbox img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 450px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row anklickbareartikel-wrapper">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6 anklickbareartikel" style="background-image: url('image_a.jpg');">

    <div class="artikelklicker" rel="" style="top:65%;left:50%;">
      <img src="icon.png" border="0">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 anklickartikelbox">
    <div class="anklickartikelfakten">
      <img src="image_b.jpg" border="0">
      <h1>Headline</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      <a href="page_x.html" target="_blank">» Linktext X</a>
      <a href="page_y.html">» Linktext Y</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(The floating is given by the bootstrap CSS)

But this unfortunately is not working. It's funny that if I activate the commented alert command redrawing for the respective element is working as expected after each confirmation of the alert box.

What did I do wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Please add your html. Are there images or other asynchronous content inside those divs?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You absolutely don't need JS for this. Forget about float, it's so 2000's. Set your parent container to `display : flex; align-items : stretch` and watch the magic. [Complete guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @JeremyThille: You're absolute right, in other projects I make heavy use of  the flexbox CSS. But in this case I'm working on a older (big) page based on Bootstrap 3 (which uses floating elements) and don't want to change this.

Comment: Ah, that's a new constraint. The code you posted doesn't make two divs side by side, but two stacked divs.

Comment: @JeremyThille: The floating is given by the bootstrap CSS - see the col-classes in the code example.